# How to get native sample rate of audio driver (Windows)

Tags: windows, audio

I have a simple sample mixer, when profiling I noticed that ~40-50% of the time is being spent resampling (44.1 => 48kHz, they must do something more sophisticated than lerp).
This step is gone when I open the playback device (DSound in my case) in 48kHz mode.
Question is: is there a way to query audio driver's default (native) sample rate to avoid resampling?
I tried searching the web/docs but found nothing, I thought this might be a simple API call.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you are still curious, I had the same question and had trouble finding answers.  Someone pointed me in the right direction, and I was able to get a working code example for getting playback properties (Win >= Vista).  You can only do this in Windows higher than XP, but that is where resampling from 44.1 to 48 can sound bad (XP had better default resampling). [How do you get the current sample rate of Windows audio playback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26286131/how-do-you-get-the-current-sample-rate-of-windows-audio-playback)